# Whats the name of the script used for "Ask Question / Answer" on this website?

Tags: scripting, name

I'm just love the way how script on this website works. It's Opensource? Where can I found it?

Regards.

Comment: which script are you talking?

Comment: looks like osqa to me: http://meta.osqa.net/questions/12/what-sites-are-running-osqa

Answer (score 2):

Server Fault uses proprietary code developed by [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "ASK BOT" is similar (or the same?)